# Is this the correct isolated circuit to control a relay output from a Raspberry Pi GPIO?

Tags: relay, gpio, output, isolated

I am making a circuit for an optically isolated relay output controlled by a Raspberry Pi GPIO pin.

I am not sure if this is the correct way of doing it. Can someone please help me out on this?

[image]

---

Edit: Modified circuit based on answer from JustMe.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SE/EE! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, and read "[ask]". Then come back and [edit] your question to clarify, please. Why do you want to opto-isolate the BJT that drives the relais? It uses the same supply is therefore not isolated. You might want to add _your understanding_ of the circuit to show us where exactly you are stumbling. Please do not add comments for new information. This is not a forum.

Comment: Why the optocoupler? The relay itself is galvanicly isolated between coil and contact.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Technically, it will work.

But it does not isolate, because you used the same ground and same 5V supply on both sides of the optoisolator.

So if you wanted to have isolation over the optocoupler between two different supplies and grounds to keep them separate, then the opto is useless and based on that the design is not correct.

Also any off leakage current through optoisolator to Q1 base may turn it on.

Comment: I plan to add this as well for the 5V isolation: B0505LS-1WR3 Isolated Module DC DC Converter 1 Output 5V 200mA 4.5V - 5.5V Input

Comment: @Praveen But it is not in the given schematics.

Comment: I have just updated the schematic based on your inputs